# Run command while key is held down in bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write bash script that plays a tone while a key is held down.

Here's what I have so far:

https://github.com/thelazymastermind/pcspkr_keyboard/blob/master/keyboard.sh

It works, but the note can't be played continously while a key is held down.

If this can't be done in bash, how can it be done with C or Python?

Answer (score 1):

Look to this projects at: http://www.shellscriptgames.com/

They use `getch.c` in order to get key input from user... So seems pure shell doesn't provide what you need.

Comment: I'm looking for a snippet of code that runs a command and doesn't stop it until the key is released. getch.c is not the answer I was looking for, sorry.